# Insert values array of php checkboxes to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have many checkboxes that should send two values to MySQL. However, I'm not getting the right value.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($rootWord != "") {
        $tag = "janaan";

        $imbuhan = array();

        // Imbuhan Kata Nama
        $result_awalan_ke = awalan_ke($rootWord, $tag);
        $imbuhan[1] = array('imbuhan' => $result_awalan_ke[0], 'pos' => $result_awalan_ke[2]);
        $resultDummy = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabletruefalse WHERE rootWord ='$result_awalan_ke[0]'");
        $exist = mysql_fetch_array($resultDummy, MYSQL_BOTH);
        if ($exist) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$result_awalan_ke[1] .' : '. $result_awalan_ke[0] . '</td><td>'. $result_awalan_ke[2].'</td><td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="imbuhan[]" value="1" /></td></tr></br>';

        }

        $result_awalan_pe = awalan_pe($rootWord, $tag);
        $imbuhan[2] = array('imbuhan' => $result_awalan_pe[0], 'pos' => $result_awalan_pe[2]);
        $resultDummy = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabletruefalse WHERE rootWord ='$result_awalan_pe[0]'");
        $exist = mysql_fetch_array($resultDummy, MYSQL_BOTH);
        if ($exist) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$result_awalan_pe[1] .' : '. $result_awalan_pe[0] . '</td><td>'. $result_awalan_pe[2].'</td><td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="imbuhan[]" value="2" /></td></tr></br>';
        }
?>
```

Instead I got the value of checkboxes. E.g. 1 or 2.

Below is the insert to MySQL code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['imbuhan'])){ 
    foreach($_POST['imbuhan'] as $value){
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablebyuser(rootWord, posWord)
        VALUES ('$value[imbuhan]', '$value[pos]')");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Side note - you need to read about SQL injection... Not sure why code like this is still being written

Comment: @Trent thanks for your concern. Will do, this is just initial phase. I will improve it

Comment: Measure twice cut once mate :)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what [imbuhan] and [pos] are... Checkboxes can only have 1 value - therefore $value is not an array and is the HTML forms "value" attribute.